# Vivado HLS 2014.4.1 crash without any error on Ubuntu 14.10 x64

Tags: ubuntu, fpga, vivado

I am using clear installations of Ubuntu 14.10 x64 and Vivado Design Suite 2014.4 with update 1. Vivado runs, but Vivado HLS crashes on start without any error.

```
user@user-Precision-M4800:/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/bin$ ./vivado_hls
================================================================
  Vivado(TM) HLS - High-Level Synthesis from C, C++ and SystemC
  Version 2014.4
  Build 1071461 on Tue Nov 18 16:42:57 PM 2014
  Copyright (C) 2014 Xilinx Inc. All rights reserved.
================================================================
@I [HLS-10] Running '/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/bin/unwrapped/lnx64.o/vivado_hls'
            for user 'user' on host 'user-Precision-M4800' (Linux_x86_64 version 3.16.0-34-generic) on Thu Apr 16 20:22:24 CEST 2015
            in directory '/opt/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/bin'
@I [HLS-10] Bringing up Vivado HLS GUI ...
```

I have tried source `settings64.sh` from vivado and run then by command vivado_hls but same thing happens. Does anyone met same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while I found out that there is error ( I have removed last line in "/Xilinx/Vivado_HLS/2014.4/bin/vivado_hls" file and ran it as root and error file appeared ). The error was SIGSEGV in main thread.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000000018f0, pid=26932, tid=139977825289984
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000000018f0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f4f1800a800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=26933, stack(0x00007f4f207d8000,0x00007f4f208d9000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x00000000000018f0
```

I found a solution  (  [Xilinx forum](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/Vivado-HLS-2014-4-Crash-on-Start-in-Ubuntu-14-04/td-p/553152) )
I just add export SWT_GTK3=0 at the top of vivado_hls file.

Comment: After running vivado hls as a root don't forget chown vivado files in your home and in /opt/Xilinx

     `sudo chown your_username /opt/Xilinx/ -R
     sudo chown your_username /home/your_username/.vivado_hls -R`

Comment: Same problem in Vivado HLS 2015.2 and Ubuntu 15.04, just use settings64.sh file from Vivado folder

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome with Vivado 2015.2